# How can I bind a form input to a command object without stripping trailing or leading whitespace

Tags: forms, grails

I have built a password change form in my Grails 3 application that allows the user to change their password. Some users want to be able to use a password beginning or ending with whitespace character(s). Is it possible to bind my text inputs to a command object without trimming whitespace characters from the beginning or end of the password string?

### Here is what I have so far

Password Change form command object

```
class PasswordChangeCommand {

  String credential
  String password1
  String password2

  static constraints = {
    credential nullable: false, blank: false
    password1 nullable: false, blank: false, validator: { val, obj, errors ->
      Zxcvbn zxcvbn = new Zxcvbn()
      if (zxcvbn.measure(val).score < 3) {
        errors.rejectValue('password1', 'password.change.password1.complexity.low',
                    "Please increase the length of your password or add numbers, symbols and capitalization")
      }
  }

  password2 nullable: false, blank: false, validator: {val, obj, errors ->
    if (!(val == obj.password1)) {
      errors.rejectValue('password2', 'password2.match.error',  [val] as Object[],
                    "Both new passwords must be the same")
    }
  }
}
```

}

HTML form field

```
<div class="form-group ${hasErrors(bean: command, field: 'password1', 'has-error')}">
  <label for="password1"><g:message code="password.new.password.message" default="New Password" /></label>
  <g:passwordField name="password1" id="password1" class="form-control pre-scrollable" value="${command.password1}" />
  <g:eachError bean="${command}" field="password1">
    <div class="field-error"><small><g:message error="${it}"/></small></div>
  </g:eachError>
</div>
```

This all works really well aside from trimming whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding) you can add the following to your config:

`grails.databinding.trimStrings = false`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is an application scoped setting. I want to affect only the password fields in my form and on the command object while maintaining current (default) behavior of all other form inputs.